# How to draw bottom half of circle drawArc Java

Tags: java, graphics2d

How does one draw the bottom half of a circle with `drawArc` in Java?

```
    g.drawArc(0,0,300,300, 0,-180); //this doesn't work
```

Comment: Explain *this doesn't work*. Do you get any output at all?

Comment: it draws an arc, but the position is wrong - i would like the ark which is drawn from top of the frame - but there is a gap between the top and diameter.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the starting direction is rotated as well:

```
g.drawArc(0, 0, 300, 300, 180, -180);
```